# How to store a string in an array in clojure

Tags: clojure

```
    (defn file-read
      [filename]
      (with-open
        [r (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
        (doseq
          [line (line-seq r)]
          *here i want to store the line in an array of strings or something*
          )
        )
      )
```

After reading the line from a text document, i want to store it. I am new to clojure and have no idea how to do this.

Comment: "Store" isn't necessarily an ideal word -- it implies state management, and I don't *think* I see that as an explicit aspect of the question. Being thoughtful and deliberate about where and how one manages state (and separating the data that does state management from the code that implements your core logic to the extent possible) is generally considered important over in Clojure-land.

Comment: ...by contrast, if you *really are* asking how to store something, then we need a lot more context to figure out the right construct for the job (of the many -- vars, atoms, refs, &c -- available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `(doseq [line (line-seq r)] ...)` just use `(doall (line-seq r))` - it will force evaluation of the `line-seq` into sequence, and return it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `doseq` is not needed and [`into-array`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into-array) would suffice.